# Can we level order print a binary search tree without using a queue in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Can we print a BST in level order without using a queue with O(n) time complexity? Below is a c++ code to do it in O(n^2) in worst case without a queue. I wonder whether we can achieve the same result in O(n). If not, can we at least improve this algorithm?

```
int height(Node* root) {
    if (root==NULL) return -1;
    int h1 = height(root->left);
    int h2 = height(root->right);
    return max(h1, h2) + 1;
}

void printLevel(Node* root, int level) {
    if (!root) return;
    if (level==0) {
        cout << root->data << " ";
        return;
    }
    printLevel(root->left, level - 1);
    printLevel(root->right, level - 1);
}
void print(Node* root) {
    int h=height(root);
    for (int i = 0; i <= h ; i++) {
        printLevel(root, i);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe word the title the way you did the question. One is asking how you do it which would be too broad, the other is a yes / no *can* you do it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Thanks for your note. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Yes, I can print a BST in level order without using a queue in O(n) (or at least, I can do it with a different structure that pretty much no-one would accuse of being a hidden queue)  However, it's kind of absurdly complex. And takes a ton of memory.  Don't do it.  Use a queue.  A queue makes the code simple, and fast.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in O(n) without a queue?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I am calling the print function once which calls the height once. To your question: I need an algorithm that uses minimal amount of extra memory. And of course if possible I want to make it as efficient as possible in time.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You can maintain *extra* information in each node which points to:

- the next item at this level if there is one; or
- the first item at the next level otherwise.

This is superimposing a queue over the search tree, and it would look something like:

```
      A        > (B)
    _/ \_
   /     \
  B   >   C    > (D)
 / \     / \
D > E > F > G  > (null)
```

Then it's a simple matter of following the different pointer chain to get breadth-first-search (BFS) order.

However, this is likely to complicate updates quite a bit and it will result in more storage being needed per node.

It's actually *more* efficient (space-wise) to use the queue method since your queue, unlike the extra pointers in the tree, will tend not to have all entries in it at once. In fact, it will never have elements in it from levels that are not directly adjacent.

By way of example, examine the classic code for BFS:

```
add root to queue
while queue is not empty:
    get node from queue
    do something with node

    if node.left exists:
        add it to queue
    if node.right exists:
        add it to queue
```

That's it, it really doesn't get any simpler than that. And the fact that you're reading an entry out of the queue before adding its children means that the storage requirements are *less* the the superimposed queue solution mentioned earlier.

Bottom line, when you find something as elegant and simple as the queue-based BFS algorithm, you want to think *very* hard before deciding to try a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can do this, without using a queue, simply the concept is that, first explicitly print the first root node. And then check whether the right and left children are available or not. If so, print them and recursively apply for the next child nodes. This idea/code is only for void functions.

```
int num = 0;
void BFS_tree(struct BT *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }

    if(num == 0){
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        num += 1;
    }

    if(root->left != NULL){
        printf("%d ", root->left->data);
    }
    if(root->right != NULL){
        printf("%d ", root->right->data);
    }

    BFS_tree(root->left);
    BFS_tree(root->right);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this ? Please consider 12-5-80-3-9-40-90-2-4-7-11-85-130-8-10-84-86 . Am i calculating wrong ? Row will be inserted in the given order btw.